# Check Constraint with Case When

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Trying to add a check constraint to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_A 
(
     NAME VARCHAR(55), 
     Country VARCHAR(50)
)

ALTER TABLE TEST_A 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_GBR_TO_IND
      CHECK (Country = CASE WHEN 'GBR' THEN 'IND' ELSE COUNTRY END);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Comment: You can't change the value to be inserted in a Check Constraint. You might want to use a trigger instead.

Comment: Why do not use a trigger?

Comment: You can use a trigger after insertin if the country = GBR then set country =IND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a Trigger instead..[You Can't use Check Constraint to change values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75098/check-constraint-with-case-statement)...

```
create trigger trg_test
on yourtable
instead of insert 
as
Begin

insert into yourtable--assuming it has only country column
select case when country='GBR' then 'IND'
else country end
from Inserted 

end
```

Comment: Fails with the following error: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: @Sharktooth:see example with trigger

Comment: Trigger is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_A ADD CONSTRAINT CK_GBR_TO_IND
CHECK (Country IN('GBR', 'IND'));
```

Comment: But I want to change on the record value only when the row inserted has GBR to IND, all other record sets should insert as usual.

Comment: @Sharktooth:  do you want to prevent records which has GBR and IND

Comment: @TheGameiswar No, if a row being inserted has Country = GBR then insert 'IND' instead, sort of how a case when works.